# How to check if record with given ID already exists using EF5 and repository

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5

For my project I am using `Entity Framework 5` with `Code First` which I use through repositories and UnitOfWork.

When I Edit/Update an entity I want to make sure that this entity exists in the database. I'm not sure how exactly this must be done. First I thought of querying for an entity with this `ID` and check if the result is null (entity with this ID is not found) and base my logic on this.

Then I decided that maybe this is not the best way so now I use this:

`if (unitOfWork.EntityRepository.GetAll().Any(r => r.EntityID == model.EntityID))`

Where `GetAll` is implemented in my `Repository` as:

```
    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return dbSet;
    }
```

I'm not sure if there is any big difference between using `Any()` and just trying to get a record with by the given `ID`, in both ways I need to query the database (I think). But since it's something that I have to do common in my code I want to know how exactly to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as for me i prefer not to use `Any()` for returning `bool` result because it generates(EF 5) pretty ugly sql:

```
new Entities().Tasks
    .Any()
```

turns into

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[Task] AS [Extent1]
)) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[Task] AS [Extent2]
)) THEN cast(0 as bit) END AS [C1]
FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
```

so in your case I would better try to get record with given id and analyze the result

Answer (score 2):

It should be equal.

The difference between the `Any()` and `FirstOrDefault()` LINQ expressions of the EF provider is that the former results in an SQL `EXISTS(...)` clause, the latter in a simple `WHERE ...`. As long as you query for an indexed column, this both is blazingly fast (and interchangeable).